# Select2 limit number of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, jquery-select2

Is there a way to limit the number of tags a user can add to an input field using Select2?

I have:

```
$('#tags').select2({
    containerCssClass: 'supplierTags',
    placeholder: "Usual suppliers...",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    placeholder: 'Usual suppliers...',
            createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
                if ($(data).filter(function() {
                    return this.name.localeCompare(term) === 0;
                }).length === 0) {
                    return {id: 0, name: term};
                }

            },
    id: function(e) {
        return e.id + ":" + e.name;
    },
    ajax: {
        url: ROOT + 'Call',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                call: 'Helpers->tagsHelper',
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {
                results: data.tags
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult: formatResult,
    formatSelection: formatSelection,
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function(i) {
            var item = this.split(':');
            data.push({
                id: item[0],
                name: item[1]
            });
        });
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

It would be great if there could be/is a simple parameter like `limit: 5` and a callback to fire when the limit is reached.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Sure, with `maximumSelectionLength` like so:

```
$("#tags").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 3
});
```

> **Maximum Selection Length**
>
> Select2 allows the developer to limit the number of items that can be
>   selected in a multi-select control.
>
> http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

It has no native callback, but you can pass a function to `formatSelectionTooBig` like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tags").select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 3,
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {

            // Callback

            return 'Too many selected items';
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U98V7/

Or you could extend `formatSelectionTooBig` like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, {
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {

            // Callback

            return 'Too many selected items';
        }
    });

    $("#tags").select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 3
    });
});
```

**Edit**

Replaced `maximumSelectionSize` with the updated `maximumSelectionLength`. Thanks @DrewKennedy!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to fire an even when this limit is reached? That would be perfect.

Comment: There is no native callback, but I added a possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Note that `maximumSelectionSize` has been replaced with `maximumSelectionLength`.

Comment: how to use this in Yii2?

Comment: Noted in the release notes, the formatters were moved to the language option.  (maximumSelected).

Comment: this still does not work when using `'tokenSeparators' => [',', ' '],`it allows to select more than the limit

Answer (score 11):

method 1

```
$("#tags").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 3
});
```

method 2

```
<select data-maximum-selection-length="3" ></select>
```

list of all available options https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't mention that the maximumSelectionLength statement should be inside the document.ready function. So for anyone who is having the same trouble I did, here is the code that worked for me.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#id").select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 3
      });

 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#keywords").select2({
    tags : true,
    width :'100%',
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    matcher : function(term,res){
        return false;
    },
    "language": {
        'noResults': function(){
            return "Type keywords separated by commas";
        }
    }
}).on("change",function(e){
    if($(this).val().length>5){
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0,5));
    }
});
```

Try like this. It'll short up to 5 keywords.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working for me, I am getting `query function not defined for Select2`, so here is another workaround.

```
        var onlyOne=false;
         $("selector").select2({
            maximumSelectionSize:function(){
                if(onlyOne==true)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 5;
            }
         });
```

This setting can be defined as function and it's called every time you start searching something.

Important thing is that you have something defined outside this select2 closure so you can check it (access it). In this case you could somewhere in your program change value of `onlyOne` and of course this returned limit can also be dynamical.

Comment: maximumSelectionSize can now be set as an integer to limit the number of selections.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
 $("#category_ids").select2({ maximumSelectionLength: 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the Get Request to action method and the Map the class properties to drop down id and text property

```
$("#DropDownId").select2({
       minimumInputLength: 3,
       maximumSelectionLength: 10,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")",
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                Title: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: $.map(response, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.Title,
                        id: item.Id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Action Method

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ActionName(string Title)
        {
            ClassName obj= new ClassName ();
            obj.Title = "PMPAK";
            obj.Id= -1;
            obj.Add(nibafInstitute);

            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```
     public class ClassName 
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```